# How to display below date format label under textbox

Tags: html, html-table

I have below table which contains two dates and displaying date format suggestion.

I want to display date format suggestion right below text box. If I use new table row, I can display that but with that there will be gap between these

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*Plan Effective Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*From: (MM/DD/YYYY)</td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px"><input type="text" id="startDate" maxlength="10" name="startDate" aria-required="true" style="width:5.5em;" value=""/></td>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*To: (MM/DD/YYYY)</td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px"><input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" maxlength="10" aria-required="true" style="width:5.5em;" value=""/></td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a line break (`<br>`), and the date format suggestion after the text box, and you should be good to go.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*Plan Effective Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*From:</td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px"><input type="text" id="startDate" maxlength="10" name="startDate" aria-required="true" style="width:5.5em;" value=""/><br>(MM/DD/YYYY)</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;text-align: right">*To:</td>
        <td style="padding-top:15px"><input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" maxlength="10" aria-required="true" style="width:5.5em;" value=""/><br>(MM/DD/YYYY)</td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```